# Multiple return values in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

So, before quite some exposition, here comes my question:

**Why is there no support for multiple return variables/values in C++ (yet)?**

To give you some more notes:

- What (if any) is conceptually a problem with multiple return values and c++?
- Is there something in the way the compiler implements returing a values from a function which makes multiple return values impossible/inefficient?

---

Having worked a lot with lua recently I've come to ask myself why C++ does not permit to return multiple values/variables from a function. To illustrate, let me give you a lua example:

```
-- get the first four values of the fibonacci sequence
local function fib4()
    return 1, 1, 2, 3

local fib0, fib1, fib2, fib3 = fib4()
```

Being able to return multiple variables/values at once is a very useful feature indeed, which I typically emulate in the C++ world by creating structs (essentially collecting the variables in a wrapper) which are returned by the function in question. If one uses this approach a lot, the soure files will be cluttered with structs each containing some variables; none of these struct needs to be an actual object (and is implemented as a complete object). In a way the conceptual problem is somewhat similar the one resulting from using structs for creating functors [instead of lambdas]:

- It destroys locality
- It introduces objects which are not conceptually objects but rather a helper

On the pro side it increases code readability:

```c++
struct point_three_dim_t {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

point_three_dim_t point = getCollisionPoint();
```

However, a priori you don't know whether the members representing the coordinates are named `x`, `y` and `z` or `first`, `second` and `third`. So again, you have to check how `point_three_dim_t` was defined. This would not be the case if

```c++
double x, y, z = getCollisionPoint();
```

were correct syntax.

Using C++11 we can achieve conceptually the same by using either `std::tuple` or `std::tie`

```c++
std::tuple<double,double,double> getCollisionPoint();

// Using std::tie
double x, y, z;
std::tie( x, y, z ) = getCollisionPoint();

// Using std::tuple
std::tuple<double,double,double> point = getCollisionPoint();
```

This gets us much closer to clean and local code, however, I think neither syntax is quite as appealing as the one I'm used from scripting languages like lua.

Comment: use a `::std::tuple`, `::std::pair` or a `struct`.

Comment: @user1095108 Did you not read his question? He does all those things, he is asking WHY he has to do those things, and there is not built in returning of multiple types. As for the original question, I rarely find that I need to return multiple things, and use a vector whenever many things are necessary (as in your fib example). If the return types are different, I usually already have a struct set up, so it isn't a clutter at all.

Comment: This is an opinion-based issue, which makes it off topic for this member of the Stack Exchange network, though perhaps one of the others makes this type of question appropriate.

Comment: What would `decltype(myfunc()) i = myfunc();` mean if `myfunc()` function returns multiple return values? Would that create multiple variables?

Comment: You can return an array of numbers(or whatever you want) from a function.

Comment: My opinion is that C++ doesn't allow this because you shouldn't have to pay for what you don't use.

Comment: Maybe down the road we can introduce some syntactic sugar that expands into `std::tie(...)`? Perhaps in C++2112.

Comment: @bstamour: I hope that in 2112, computers will be a bit smarter than to require esoteric things like programming languages in order to be instructed.

Comment: Did you make a standards proposal allowing multiple return values?

Comment: `double x, y, z = getCollisionPoint();` _is_ correct syntax.

Comment: @Yakk I know, and that's my wish too. However I couldn't resist throwing in a reference to the greatest rock band on earth (Rush)

Comment: @mah Whether this is useful is opinion based, however, my question (if you read through that wall of text carefully) is whether there are any _conceptual_ problems/compiler problems which don't allow returning multiple values or make it inefficient.

Comment: @Nazar554 At first glance this would be a problem indeed. However, if you think about it, essentially it would mean that the type of i is that of a collection of variables. Definitely something new in the C++ world, yet nothing totally off the table under the pretense of my question.

Comment: @Casey Yes, phrasing, I know. But I'm sure you know what I meant.

Comment: There's no reason it couldn't be done, and the ability to return a `std::tuple` via `std::tie` proves that.

Comment: [Recent discussion of multiple-value returns on the std-proposals list](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/VROimyg83fc).